# Efficient way to get median of all subsets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, median

Given a finite discrete set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ with cardinality $k$.

The are $2^k$ subsets. For any given subset, there is a median associated with it (Define the median of $\emptyset$ as 0).

Wondering if there are any smart ways to get the $2^k$ medians.

Comment: I don't know a smart way to get the medians, but they are not $2^k$. I generated several sets of $10$ "real" numbers, with $2^{10}$ subsets and their distinct median are always $56$. It looks like an interesting phenomenon

Comment: I tried other cardinalities and got an amazing result. The number of distinct medians of the subsets of $n$ numbers is $$\frac{1}{2} \left(n^2+n+2\right)$$

Comment: interesting, how did you get that number? would love to hear!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009926/median-of-the-subsets-of-a-finite-set-of-real-numbers

Comment: ah right, so you guessed the formula from observation

Comment: I am not clever enough to prove it :)

Comment: i mean, it would be nicer, if you mention this part explicitly. it could be some other function that has a similar form? it could mislead folks trying to prove with the specific function.

Comment: It is a *conjecture*. If it is false, contributor will soon find out. People are very very clever here

Comment: lol, ok, really interesting conjecture!

Comment: lol, the smart proof is a bit "disappointing"

Answer (score 0):

The possible medians are:

- any of the $k$ values
- (if you define the median of an even-sized set as halfway between the two most central  values) any mean of two of the $k$ values
- $0$ for the empty set

That makes $k+{k \choose 2}+1 = \frac12k^2 +\frac12k+1$ potentially distinct values for subset medians and explains how to find them; it may turn out that there are some duplicates.