# Median of the subsets of a finite set of real numbers

Tags: median

Starting from this$^1$ question, using *Mathematica* I did the following.

Generated a sequence of $n$ random distinct "real" numbers.

Computed the median of the $2^n$ subsets (conventionally $\emptyset$ has a median zero) and deleted duplicates.

The number $m$ of distinct medians I got, was constant for fixed $n$ and followed a simple rule
$$m=\frac{1}{2} \left(n^2+n+2\right)$$

The code I used is the following

```
Table[{n, 
  Length[DeleteDuplicates[
    Median /@ Subsets[Table[RandomReal[10^12], {k, 1, n}]]]]}, {n, 1, 20}]
```

Do you know why this happens?

**Edit**

There are exceptions

Consider $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

The value predicted by the formula is $m=11$ but we have
$$\mathcal{P}(A)=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\\\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$$

Medians are $$\left\{0,1,2,3,4,\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{5}{2},\frac{5}{2},3,\frac{7}{2},2,2,3,3,\frac{5}{2}\right\}$$ and the distinct ones are only $8$:
$$\left\{0,1,2,3,4,\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2},\frac{7}{2}\right\}$$
[1]: [Efficient way to get median of all subsets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009872/efficient-way-to-get-median-of-all-subsets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Median has to be equal to either some number from $x_1,\ x_2,\ldots,x_n$, or arithmetic mean of two of these numbers (plus our case with zero). So number of different results is

$$ {{n}\choose{0}} + {{n}\choose{1}} + {{n}\choose{2}}  = \frac{n^2+n+2}{2} $$

Comment: this would be an upper bound

Comment: @pengyu I wrote this answer before post was edited, so I kept to the interpretation where our numbers are quite random, in particular they are non-zero and $a+b \neq c+d \neq 2e$ for different $a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ e$ in our set. Then all of our results are different and attained.

Comment: for a large enough $n$ the `a+b \neq c +d \neq 2e$, would be too strict though.